# Sorting a List of Doubles

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list by a value in one of the x objects the list holds. Here is the order i need:

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.10
1.11
1.12
4.1
4.2
4.15
```

I've tried the following:

```
var lRetItems = lExportItems.OrderBy(d => d.linkid);
```

and

```
IEnumerable<item> lRetItems = 
from x in lExportItems
orderby x.linkid
select x;
```

but neither give me the order i want as with these approaches 1.10 follows 1.1 instead of 1.2 following 1.1. Here's an example of the incorrect ordering the above approaches provide:

```
1
1.1
1.10
1.11
1.12
1.2
1.3
1.4
...
```

Does anyone have any idea how i might order the list in the same way as the first example?

Comment: Nope, definitely doubles.

Comment: @DanHall They _are_ doubles, but what you _want_ are strings.

Comment: If they're `double`-s, how is `1.1` different from `1.10`?

Comment: This is terribly unsafe: a `1.3` is behind the curtains usually something `1.299999999...`-ish. So that would mean that `1.3` can be the last element.

Comment: @xxbbcc correct!!!

Comment: This is safe as i can guarantee the values are 1.1, 1.2, 1.3...2,1, 2.2, 2.3 and so on. I'll fiddle with data types and see where that gets me. Thanks so far.

Comment: Also like the fact you say that those are double values, but want that following order ``4.1
4.2
4.15`` you know that ``4.15`` is smaller than ``4.2``? do you?

Comment: Ok tried Strings but it has the exact sequence as mentioned in the original post using the same approaches.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you want. You want to sort by the whole part of the number and then by the fractional part. This will be problematic because you want `.1` to be treated as if it is 1/10th the size of `.10` which will not be the case.

Comment: From your description, you appear to be wanting to store a pair of integers in a single value. Using a double, by putting one int in the units part and the other in the fractional part won't work (because .1 and .10 won't be distinguishable, for example, and because doubles don't always store exact values you put into them). You'll need to find a different way to store this that is more appropriate.

Comment: @DanHall: I think we are all still slightly confused about how you have doubles that are `1.1` and `1.10` since when stored as double there would be no way to tell those two numbers apart...

Comment: Please provide a small example of the input and output. You have everyone guessing here.

Comment: @RufusL who doesnt like a good guessing game :)

Comment: Yes, a small but complete example of what you are trying to do would be greatly appreciated. eg show us something like `List<double> input = new List<double>(){1, 1.1, 1.2, ...}` with your actual values in.

Comment: @Chris it is almost useless, because you cannot capture the difference between `1.1` and `1.10` in a double List. you cannot even transform them differently into strings... unless with a some kind of if-logic

Comment: *roboter voice* can not proceed! input more data! 1.1 isnt larger or smaller than 1.10! it is the same number *roboter shuts down*

Comment: If you want the sorted like that why not write your own implementation of `System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<double>` and provide your own comparison implementation? As far as 1.1 vs 1.10, you can't tell the difference unless they are strings as these are the exact same value.

Comment: [does not compute...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBAijg5Betw)

Comment: Haha loving the progression of comments here, I have indeed left quite a mystery! I moved over to string for the linkid but that doesn't like it either as the exact same order is returned. It seems I'll have to create a custom comparer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to picture these doubles as your national currency. For the sake of example, let's assume american dollars. US$1.2 is more money than US$1.10, which, by its turn, is the same as US$1.1, aka, (US$1.10 == US$ 1.1), which wouldn't produce the same result if those were strings, and not numbers.

If those were strings, "1.10" would come after "1.5" because it has a greater length, not because of its content. Try that out when you can.

Comment: Thanks but strings come up with exactly the same sort order :-/

Comment: Try using an actual List<string> instead of IQueryable or IEnumerable.
List<String> lRetItems  = lExportItems.Select(l => l.linkid).ToList();